# how to get the speed for a car speedometer inputted as a picture in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

[image: SPEEDOMETER]

how to get the speed of the car as an integer with the picture of speedometer in matlab as an input, as in this example the output is zero

a method or a code for this will help so much, thanks

Comment: This is too large a problem for a single answer. For digit detection you would have to find a library that implements [optical character recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) (and detection for that matter). The speedometer dial would look different in every car. You might be able to get away with doing a [hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) and searching for the intersection of the dial with one of the numbers.

Comment: actually I will be focusing on one type of cars, or in fact, its not a car, its the value of some electrical machine. somehow I can have a hypothetical circle that ranges from 0 to 360 degrees. I can assume that, if  the angle of the red pixels are in the position of 225 degree, then that means the value of the speed is 0km/h. and if the angle of the red pixels is 180 degree, than that means the value of the speed is 30 km/h as you can see from the picture, and so on. is that applicable and does it make sense ? @eigenchris

Comment: I see. Still, I think this question is too big for this website. If you run into a specific problem we can help you solve it.

Comment: I don't think its so complicated, may be someone has done it before : )
thanks @eigenchris

Comment: Parond, I guess I didn't realize you we saying all the speedometers would have the same values across all cars, so OCR wouldn't be necessary. I would try the hough transform approach I mentioned in my first comment and get the angle of the line.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use the `Orientation` parameter of the `regioprops` function. With your image, I extracted the red layer to form a binarized image:

[image]

Then I found the orientation of the biggest object. Here is the code:

```
% --- Parameters
th = 130;

% --- Load image
Img = imread('Image.jpg');

% --- Binarization based on the red layer
BW = (Img(:,:,1)-(Img(:,:,2)+Img(:,:,3))/2)>th;

% Get the main object's orientation
R = regionprops(BW, {'Area', 'Orientation'});
[~,I] = max([R(:).Area]);
theta = R(I).Orientation;
```

The value of the angle `theta` (which is ~35° in this case) is defined between 0 and 180°. To obtain a definition on a complete 360°, you will have to refine the code, for instance by looking at the angle between the centroid of the object and the center of the bounding box, which are btw two quantities accessible with `regionprops`.

Best,